# Security concerns between a thin client in Swing and MySql directely

Tags: java, mysql, swing, security

I have a Swing application that connect directly to MySql Database for user authentication.

- The bit code of the application will be available on Internet for download
- The connections information are in static variables

I know that I should've programmed a server to handle the authentication, but the initial requirement didn't mention the authentication use case

My question is : is Obfuscating the application is enough to encode the connection information ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know what they say about security through obscurity! (Hint: it's not security at all).

Encrypt it (though since there seems to be no server side component, I dont see a feasable way of doing this). Or do the authentication server side like you said.

Answer (score 1):

No, most people will be able to reverse-engineer or decompile the byte code and see the variables. You can try it yourself and see that you have not really hidden anything from any advanced user.

In this instance, you really want to have a service in between the client and the database to handle the authentication, like you said.

The service would then have user accounts that would allow/disallow access to the database.

edit:

try using [this](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) decompiler and see for yourself that this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something quick and dirty but in the end I realize that doing the right thing wouldn't take too much either. What I did is having a [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) that expose the [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) on the server side, a server and a client objects communicating over Java Socket.

Then, instead of calling the DAO from the client directly, I invoke a method on the server by passing the name of the method as String. And with the help of reflection, the facade calls the right method on the DAO.

I think I should encode the string and add a security Token.

  -